# Visual Basic how to use for strucure?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, for-loop, textbox, show-hide

I am new to programming.  I am learning visual basic.  I am using visual basic 2008 and I need some help with the following code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object....
    Dim i As New Integer
    Dim nrnote As New Integer
    nrnote = TextBoxnrnote.Text
    For i = 1 To nrnote
        TextBox.i.Show()
    Next
    Timer1.Stop()
```

The above code causes the following error:

> 'i' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'.

`nrnote` is the max number of text boxes that should appear.  For instance, if I enter `nrnote = 5`, then text boxes 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 should become visible on the form.

Comment: You should create an array of textboxes.

Comment: Either you need to add them all to the form at design-time, and store references to them in an array, as @SLaks said, or access them by name via the `Me.Controls` collection, or else you need to dynamically load the text boxes.  However, doing something like this is probably a bad idea.  I would recommend using another control that supports multiple items, such as the `DataGridView`.

Comment: hey SlaKS .. how can i do that... i'm fist time programming... i mean by 40 minutes ago i'm learning commands :D

Comment: Do you already have all of the text boxes on the form at design-time?  If so, what are they called?

Comment: Hmm... it would take a lot of time if i do it with lots of "if " structures....

Comment: i got 8 hidden txtboxes..(texbox1..8) and they are hidden..... i want to introduce value 4 in a textbox and first 4 textboxes to become visible

i mean for i =1 to number of boxes i want to show
              textbox(i).show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are named consistently (e.g. `TextBox1`, `TextBox2`, `TextBox3`), then you can do it like this:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To nrnote
    Dim t As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls("TextBox" & i.ToString()), TextBox)
    t.Visible = True
Next
```

Otherwise, you could add the text boxes to an array, like this:

```
Dim textBoxes() As TextBox = { FirstTextBox, SecondTextBox, ThirdTextBox }
For i As Integer = 1 To nrnote
    textBoxes(i).Visible = True
Next
```

Comment: I am a software engineer in the public-safety market (e.g. police software).  If you click my name, you can see my summary.

Comment: Cool ! And sorry for my bad english :))